# The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK - IntelliJ JavaFX JDK on windows

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, intellij-14

I am new to Java programming. I wanted to learn JavaFX and from [**this**](https://www.openjfx.io) I installed the SDK. I was using [**this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHj6zbH3inI") video to setup the SDK  but even I set the `JAVA_HOME` directory, I always get  the **error**:

> **The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within intellij:

File -> Project Structure -> Libraries

click the "plus" button to add a new library, click "Java", and point to the `lib` directory in your JavaFX SDK directory.

example: `C:\Users\sparrow\.jdks\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib`

This information is documented in the "Getting Started" guide on the openjfx.io website.

https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij